# Searching string among 5Gb of text files

Tags: python, powershell, batch-file

I have several CSV files (~25k in total) with a total size of ~5Gb. This files are in a network path and I need to search for several strings inside all these files and to save the files' names (in an output file for example) where these strings are found.

I've already tried two things:

1. With Windows I've used *findstr* : `findstr /s "MYSTRING" *.csv > Output.txt`
2. With Windows PowerShell: `gci -r "." -filter "*.csv" | Select-String "MYSTRING" -list > .\Output.txt`

I also can use Python but I don't really think it'll be faster.

There is any other way to speed up this search ?

---

More precision: the structure of all the files is different. They are CSV but they could be just simple TXT files

Comment: Try ripgrep - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494595/how-can-i-search-a-specific-list-of-files-with-ripgrep

Comment: since the files are in network path it'll be IO bound and you won't be able to make it any faster than the network speed

Comment: You need `findstr /M` to get the names of the files containing the search string. `/S` is "including subfolders" (recursive) (probably a typo in the question, as you claim to actually get the filenames)

Comment: Will it be better to concatenate everything in just one big file to avoid de IO access time ?

Comment: 25000 files that sum up to 5GB or one file that has 5GB - same amount of data to be transferred (plus the time to concat them; and how to get the individual filenames then?). Only way to speed it up is to run the script directly on the server that hosts the network drive (if they let you)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to go through large csv files. You will use the read_csv() method to read the contents of the csv files, then use the query() method to filter out the columns and then use to_csv() to export those results in a separate csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv')
result = df.query('column_name == "filtered_strings"')
result.to_csv('filtered_result.csv', index=False)
```

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Most of the CSV files are not that big and their structure is not the same so the string can be anywhere. I think this method won't improve the performance since it's needed to 'open' each one of them

Answer (score 0):

One of the fastest ways to search in text files using PowerShell is [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.3) with parameters `-File FILENAME -Regex`.

This won't make a big difference though, unless you avoid the I/O bottleneck of the network, by running the search code on the server, e. g. using [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7.3). Of course you need to have permissions to be able to run scripts on the remote server.

```sh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName TheRemoteMachine {
    Get-ChildItem C:\Location\Of\Files -Recurse -Filter *.csv -PV file | ForEach-Object {
        switch -File $_.Fullname -Regex {
            'MYSTRING|ANOTHERSTRING' { $file.FullName; break }
        }
    }
} | Set-Content output.txt
```

This outputs the full paths of files that contain the sub string "MYSTRING" or "ANOTHERSTRING", which gets received on the local machine  and stored in a local file.

`switch -File $_.Fullname -Regex` reads the current file line by line, applying the regular expression to each line. We use `break` to stop searching when the first match has been found.

Parameter `-PV file` (alias of [`-PipeLineVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.3#-pipelinevariable)) for `Get-ChildItem` is used so we have access to the current file path in the `switch` statement. In the switch statement `$_` denotes the current RegEx match, so it hides `$_` from the `ForEach-Object` command. Using `-PV` we provide another name for the `$_` variable of `ForEach-Object`.